# obj-c : iphone programming disabling the round off of a number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, numbers, rounding

i need to show a number to a user : 1.96666777 (timeHour)

```
moduloformat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f hours ",timeHour];
```

but it is rounding off the number automaticly. It gives "2" and i want to show "1"
i could use a NSrange and take the first number but i wanna know how to deal with this.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
moduloformat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f hours ",floor( timeHour )];
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to just cast the float to an int. When you do that the decimal places get chopped off and no rounding occurs.

```
moduloformat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i hours ", (int)timeHour];
```